# How does Turbotax get your W-2 from the previous year without user input?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, form-w-2, turbotax

How does Turbotax get  your W-2 from the previous year without user input? Does it use the prior year's W-2 to populate the current tax year's W-2?

Also when Turbo tax says you will get a refund next year, is that true?

Answer (score 3):

> How does Turbotax get your W-2 from the previous year without user
> input?

If you use tax software multiple years, the first thing they do is locate the previous years tax file on the computer and ingest the key information. They pull your personal details: name, address, DOB, SSN, dependents, and marital status. They will ask you if any of these have changed.

They also pull the basic financial information: W-2, 1099's, charities, schooling.

> Does it use the prior year's W-2 to populate the current tax year's
> W-2?

They use that financial information to pre-populate those sections. They use this to remind you of all the "companies" that you had relevant income and deductions with the previous year. It also cuts down on data entry if nothing has changed for the basic information on those tax forms. Of course the financial numbers change every year, but if you didn't move, change employers, or switch banks the basic data on these forms didn't change.

They also pull all the answers to the questions from the previous year. They use this to remind you what was important the previous year. In my state we have a car tax, which can be used when itemizing. If the previous year the  car tax was $789, when moving though that section this year I will see that I had claimed $789 last year, so I should remember to look for my numbers for this year.

> Also when Turbo tax says you will get a refund next year, is that
> true?

Tax software has the ability to help you forecast next years tax situation. But it is only able to do this if you know the relevant numbers, what changes will occur, and the government doesn't change the tax law.